# Module and .less file not getting added to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

I'm working on a Magento 2.4 project.
I started by creating a new theme from the official documentation, and it was working smoothly as follows:
[image]

Then I tried adding a custom css to the home page.

however, when I try to add a .less file to my css directory, as mentioned in this video,
[CSS in responsive design](https://youtu.be/svohC_QJBtU)

The website frontend just clash:

[image]

It fixes when I run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

It was mentionned in the video that **it has something to do with permissions of my files and directories**  but I dont know if this is the case or how to properly fix it without ruining my installation.

It's worth to note that same thing happens when i try adding **MarkShust_PageBuilderSourceCode** module by runnning:

```
bin/magento module:enable MarkShust_PageBuilderSourceCode
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Once done, the module folder is added prefectly into vendor directory.
when I refresh the page to see the module, the page css crush again.
I run :

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

but cant find the module name added and have to run the status command again

Comment: I think it had something to do with my .htaccess file. but I'm not sure as to how to fix it or set permissions accordingly to avoid this issue from now on